# Using apply functions

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame having these columns

```
Qty  Sales Price  COGS  
  1          500   200  
  2          900   400   
  3         1000   300   
  1          300   150
```

I want to calculate the profit for every row. So for row 1 if Sales Price - COGS (500-200) profit is 300.
one condition is that if qty is more than 1 then Qty*Sales Prce- Qty*COGS= gross profit.

I used loop

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Data)) {
  if(Data[i,"Qty"]<=1) {Data[i,"Margin"]<-Data[i,"Sales.Price"]-Data[i,"COGS"]}    
  if(Data[i,"Qty"]>=1){Data[i,"Margin"]<-Data[i,"Qty" * "Sales.Price"]-Data[i,"Qty * "COGS"]}
}

But
```

I want to use apply function

and return my answer in data frame as Margin appended as an vector in my current data frame and not as list or matrix.

```
Qty    Sales Price    COGS    Margin  
  1            500     200       300  
  2            900     400      1000  
  3           1000     300      2100  
  1            300     150       150
```

Comment: Please read `?Arithmetic` and then `?S4groupGeneric`, many of the functions in R are vectorized (not only on vectors but on matrices and even data frames). Writing unnecessary  loops in `apply` instead of a `for` won't get you far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for an apply function. You can just use a vectorized approach:

```
Data$Margin <- Data$Qty * (Data$Sales.Price - Data$COGS)
```

Comment: Thanks for such a simple answer:)